# Plot three graphs in one

Tags: r, plot, ecdf

I have three empirical distribution functions and I would like to plot these into one graph for an overview. 
The x label should say 'Bedienzeit (s) and I would like different colors and a legend. Unfortunately all I am trying, does not really work well.

Could anyone of you tell me how to do this?

Thanks a lot!!

```
Daten <- read_excel("Input/Daten_ohne_Anton_Leonie.xlsx")
G_40_TmK_Alle_VP <- Daten$G_40_TmK
G_40_BmK_Alle_VP <- Daten$G_40_BmK
G_40_WoK_Alle_VP <- Daten$G_40_WoK

#ECDF TmK
G_40_TmK_Alle_VP_ECDF <- ecdf(G_40_TmK_Alle_VP)

#ECDF BmK
G_40_BmK_Alle_VP_ECDF <- ecdf(G_40_BmK_Alle_VP)

#ECDF WoK
G_40_WoK_Alle_VP_ECDF <- ecdf(G_40_WoK_Alle_VP)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Not sure if this will work as you didn't provide a sample of your data.
```par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(G_40_TmK_Alle_VP_ECDF, xlab="Bedienzei", main="need_data_sample")
plot(G_40_BmK_Alle_VP_ECDF, xlab="Bedienzei", main="need_data_sample")
plot(G_40_WoK_Alle_VP_ECDF, xlab="Bedienzei", main="need_data_sample")```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point for you :

```
plot(ecdf(1:10), col = 1, xlab = "Bedienzeit (s)")
plot(ecdf(rep(1:2, 5)), add = TRUE, col = 2)
plot(ecdf(rep(1:5, 2)), add = TRUE, col = 3)
legend(8, 0.3, legend = paste("Série", 1:3), col = 1:3, lty = 1)
```

`add = TRUE` allows to plot several series.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to specify that the legend says TmK, BmK and WoK instead of Series 1, Series 2, Series 3?

Comment: @Annsophie yes replace the argument legend `paste("Serie", 1:3)` by your vector of names

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: One more question - sorry :) do you know how to create a line instead of these steps? type = "l" doesnt work somehow:plot(G_40_TmK_Alle_VP_ECDF,verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE, xlab ='Bedienzeit in s', ylab = '', main = 'Empirische Verteilungsfunktionen (ECDF) bei 40 Grad\n Gesamte Stichprobe ', col = 3)
lines(G_40_BmK_Alle_VP_ECDF,verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE, col = 2)
lines(G_40_WoK_Alle_VP_ECDF,verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE, col = 4)
legend(15, 0.8, legend = c("TmK", "BmK", "WoK"), col = c(3,2,4), lty = 1)

Comment: Plot is achieved with `plot.ecdf`. `ecdf(x)` is a function. Here is a trick to do what you want : `plot(1:10, ecdf(1:10)(1:10), type = "l")`